# Unable to access robots.txt file on tomcat 6 server

Tags: windows, tomcat, hosting, tomcat6, robots.txt

Sorry if i sound silly, but I'm facing a weird problem.
I made a robots.txt file and uploaded it to my Tomacat 6 webapps/ROOT folder, but when I try to access it through http://www.this-is-not-my-real-domain-name.com/robots.txt I get a 404 not found error.
I restarted the server multiple times, without success.
What am i doing wrong?
Isn't it supposed to be simple.
Please help me out.
I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try putting it in same folder which root is in.